# crud operation on nested array mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

```js
[
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Afghanistan",
  "iso3": "AFG",
  "iso2": "AF",
  "states": [
    {
      "id": 3901,
      "name": "Badakhshan",
      "state_code": "BDS",
      "latitude": "36.73477250",
      "longitude": "70.81199530",
      "type": null,
      "cities": [
        {
          "id": 52,
          "name": "Ashkāsham",
          "latitude": "36.68333000",
          "longitude": "71.53333000"
        },]
```

```js
 let filter = { iso2: country_code ,name:country_name,"states.state_code":state_code,"states.name":state_name };
    let newvalues = { $push:
    {"states.$[].cities": [{  name: state_name, code:city_code }]}}
    dbo.collection("countries").updateOne(filter, newvalues,{upsert:true}, async function (err, result) {
      if (err) {
        res.json({success:false, response: err.message,statusbar:err})
      }
      res.json({success: true, statuscode: 200, response: result})
      db.close();
```

Hi all I am trying to add,delete and update city which is as object inside a states array i tried as above did not workout need a suggestion tqq

Comment: Are there any error messages?  When you retrieve the same doc, is is unchanged?

Comment: no i am not getting any error messages at the same time its not working ,is there any other way can you suggest??

Comment: After the `updateOne`, the document is unchanged?  When I try the same `update` on mongoplayground.net, it works.